# Click back button twice to go back in history

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a single page application and would like to navigate through the history using browser back and forward button. I am facing an issue when i click the back button once it does not navigate to the previous page but stays on the current page. Then when i click the browser back again it takes me to the previous page. I have tried out the following.

```js
class PageModule {
      constructor() {
        window.addEventListener("popstate",function(){
          this.handleHistory(true);
        }.bind(this),false);
       }

  

handleHistory(popStateEventFired = false){
    if(popStateEventFired){
      history.replaceState();
    }else{
      history.pushState(null,null);
    }

    history.pushState(null,null);
    
  }
```

When i issue a search i add the search param as a query param in the url `?question=testsearch` and call the method `handleHistory()`. I have checked other answers to similar problem but they dont seem to help.
I have to do this using vanilla javascript or knockoutjs as we maintain HTML bindings using knockoutjs but am not able to achieve this properly.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: How to close this question? I found the root cause and my problem was due to incorrect implementation

Comment: Could you edit the question with the answer to your problem? I'm in a similar problem myself.

I believe you can also just write a comment and approve it to be the correct answer to this.

Comment: @Moataz Alsayed .. I am using a builder environment along with vanilla js. The problem was that i was pushing the state twice at a certain place. If you could share your code and problem maybe i could be of better help

Comment: @Aproov I think my issue was with how sharepoint deals with click the back option. I tried many things but eventually left the project and not sure if it's solved now or just ignored. Will try to add my answer insha'allah when I see the code again if it is now solved.